# Is there anything wrong with assigning dynamically created objects to pointers that are private members of a class?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, dynamic, memory-leaks

For exemple, say that I have a Game class:

```
class Game{
public:
    Game();
    ~Game();

    void CreateWindowClass(HINSTANCE);
    void CreateRessources(HINSTANCE);

    void ShowMainScreen();

    Winsock* CreateWinsock();

    MessageLog* CreateMessageLog();

    D2DResources* CreateD2DResources(HWND);

    HWND Getm_hWnd();

public:
    D2DResources* pD2DResources;
    Winsock* pWinsock;
    MessageLog* pMessageLog;

private:
    HWND m_hWnd;

};
```

and the 3 pointers inside Game are assigned like this:

```
Winsock* Game::CreateWinsock()
{
    pWinsock = new Winsock;

    return pWinsock;
}
```

Will this cause any problem? Also, will I delete the dynamically created object like this: delete pWinsock;?

Comment: Those are public members, but smart pointers make doing so a lot more safe.

Comment: You have to be careful that no one else deletes the pointer.

Comment: Can I use smart pointers with virual studio 2010?

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron, Sure, Boost has `shared_ptr`, and there's always `std::auto_ptr` if you know the kinks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pWinsock` is a public member, but either way there is nothing wrong with this. Both `pWinsock` and the pointer return value of the function are pointing at the dynamically allocated `Winsock` object. As long as you `delete` the object at some point, you don't have a memory leak.

The only issue here is that the client of this function may `delete` the pointer themselves, while your `Game` object might rely on the `pWinsock` pointer being valid for a particular duration (perhaps for its entire lifetime). You can best express your intent by using a smart pointer. A `std::shared_ptr<Winsock>` would be a good choice here, as your `Game` object creates the `Winsock` and then shares ownership with the client.

Answer (score 3):

I would avoid exposing public fields and sharing raw pointers like that. You're breaking encapsulation and making memory management more difficult. Instead use accessor/mutator functions, as in Java. The compiler will inline these away.

The problem with returning the `Winsock*` from `CreateWinsock` is that it isn't clear who "owns" the Winsock object anymore, since the method resembles a factory constructor, where the caller owns it, but you're setting a member field to it, so the host `Game` object really owns it.

I suggest using a smart-pointer like `shared_ptr` when exposing the Winsock object so the lifetime of the Winsock is controlled.

The `Winsock` object will not be deleted automatically unless you delete it from within your `Game::~Game()` destructor.